# How can i get number of user with < and > of x access?

Tags: sql, sql-server

if this query take me a number of users without access:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(table1.IdUtente) AS UserWithoutAccess
FROM  table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.IdUtente = table2.IdAttivazione
WHERE (table1.Demo = 1) AND (table1.idRivenditore = 0) 
AND (table1.IdGruppo NOT IN (29, 130,117))
AND (table2.IdAttivazione IS NULL)
```

The tables are:
[image: tables]

How can i do the same query for users that had accessed for minus or plus than x times. For example User Accessed more than 600 times how can i do the query?
Thanks for help
T.M.

Comment: `select distinct count()` actually makes no sense.  I think you should provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Can you provide DDL of tables and more details? Is IdAttivazione FK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT idUtente, count(*) as LoginCount
FROM table1 A
JOIN table2 B ON A.idUtente = B.IdAttivazione
WHERE (table1.Demo = 1) AND (table1.idRivenditore = 0) 
AND (table1.IdGruppo NOT IN (29, 130,117))
GROUP BY idUtente
HAVING Count(*) > 600
```

- Inner Join makes sure that you work with the users that have logged in at least once
- You need to remove `table2.IdAttivazione IS NULL` from WHERE conditions, as this works only when you are looking for users without logins
- HAVING COUNT(*) > X will give you logins (IdUtente) that had more than X number of logins